# How to find all newly modified files after a specific time ?(windows command line)

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I can use `forfiles /P directory /S /D +01/04/2015` to list all newly modified files after 01/04/2015. But I searched a lot about forfiles and didn't see any parameters about it can let me filter the files based on their modified time(not date).
How to find files based on modified time ? (use forfiles or other command line.including find the file in the sub directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about PowerShell?  This will find all files modified in the last two hours.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\your\path\here -Recurse |
  Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-2) }
```

Change what's on the right of '-ge' to suit your needs; you can even specify an exact date/time

```
... -ge (Get-Date '20 Sep 2016 23:14') }
```

Comment: I tired but it only displays the directory. But I need all the files.

Comment: That will list all files. Are you sure you got the date right, and that the files have been modified on the time period specified? If you leave off the | at rhe end of the first line and all of the second line, it should give you a full list of files. The second line just limits what gets returned from that list.

Comment: It works this time I really don't know why .....

Comment: Glad it worked out for you in the end.  :-)